# How can I have a sticky Header in react js and using Tailwind style

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my journey of learning Reactjs/nextjs i'am trying to build the google clone.
My Header Component has two main div
like the google page search:

The 1st div contains : - google logo - form -

The 2nd div contains: - list options of: All, Images, Videos etc

I want to make the header sticky and only shows the first div while scrolling down to the page. Any help please of how to implement this?

You can take a look at google search page and scroll down to get the result wanted: [while scrolling down the page](https://www.google.com/search?q=search&source=hp&ei=CAnoYcaONsnSa8zWmegE&iflsig=ALs-wAMAAAAAYegXGBJA6RDJ6u1Obh2phm5QoghoenSV&ved=0ahUKEwjGsu-e7b31AhVJ6RoKHUxrBk0Q4dUDCAc&uact=5&oq=search&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQguEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEOgsILhCABBDHARDRAzoLCC4QgAQQxwEQowJQAFiWBmDKDWgAcAB4AIABjAGIAeQFkgEDMC42mAEAoAEB&sclient=gws-wiz)

Here is my Header Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import Image from 'next/image';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import {
  MicrophoneIcon,
  SearchIcon,
  XIcon,
  CogIcon,
  ViewGridIcon,
} from '@heroicons/react/solid';

function Header() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const searchInputRef = useRef(null);
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');

  const search = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const term = searchInputRef.current.value;

    if (!term) return;
    router.push(`/search?term=${term}`);
  };

  return (
    <header className='flex flex-col sticky top-0 pt-4 bg-white scroll:shadow-md border-b-2'>
      {/* 1st DIV */}
      <div className='flex p-2'>
        <Image
          loading='lazy'
          src='https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png'
          alt='Google Logo'
          width={82}
          height={30}
          className='cursor-pointer'
        />
        <form className='flex flex-grow w-4/5 px-6 py-2 ml-10 mr-5 border border-gray-200 rounded-full shadow-md items-center'>
          <input
            ref={searchInputRef}
            className='flex-grow focus:outline-none cursor-pointer'
            type='text'
            value={value}
            onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
          />
          {value && (
            <XIcon
              className='h-5 sm:mr-3 text-gray-500 cursor-pointer'
              // onClick={() => (searchInputRef.current.value = '')}
              onClick={() => setValue('')}
            />
          )}
          <MicrophoneIcon className='h-5 hidden sm:inline-block text-blue-500 border-l-2 pl-4 border-gray-300' />
          <SearchIcon className='h-7 pl-1 text-[#4285f4] cursor-pointer hidden sm:inline-block' />
          <button className='hidden' type='submit' onClick={search}>
            Search
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>

      {/* 2nd DIV */}
      <div className='flex space-x-4 p-6 cursor-pointer'>
        <p>All</p>
        <p>Images</p>
        <p>Video</p>
        <p>Books</p>
        <p>More</p>
      </div>
    </header>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This could be done with help of CSS and js
[w3scools example here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_navbar_sticky)

```js
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.header {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

#navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

#navbar a.active {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
}

.content {
  padding: 16px;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
  <h2>Scroll Down</h2>
  <p>Scroll down to see the sticky effect.</p>
</div>

<div id="navbar">
  <a class="active" href="javascript:void(0)">Home</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)">News</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)">Contact</a>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <h3>Sticky Navigation Example</h3>
  <p>The navbar will stick to the top when you reach its scroll position.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How to achieve this using react hooks?

Comment: this explains it more but still it is achieved with css 
https://dev.to/dalalrohit/sticky-navbar-from-scratch-using-react-37d5

Comment: in tailwind css we can achieve what is in the article only by adding the property "sticky" to the className. but i want to filter my sticky header, and only the 1st div will be shown as we scroll down the page. and the 2nd div will not appear as we scroll down

Comment: than you can use  conditional rendering

Comment: how to use them? am newbie to reactjs